# How to find a closed form of $\displaystyle A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\varphi\sqrt k\right\rfloor$?

Tags: calculus, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

When I was trying approximate this sum
$\displaystyle A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\varphi\sqrt k\right\rfloor$,
where $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ is the golden-ratio,
I found that
$B_n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{2\varphi\sqrt n(n+1)}{3}-\dfrac{\sqrt n(2\sqrt n+1)}{4}\right\rfloor$ is a good approximation.
Can you help me proving that $A_n\simeq B_n$?
Also, find a closed form of the sum $A_n$.

Comment: A simpler asymptotics: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left\lfloor {\varphi \sqrt k } \right\rfloor }  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\varphi \sqrt k }  + \mathcal{O}(n) = \varphi \left( {\int_0^n {\sqrt t \,\mathrm{d}t}  + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt n )} \right) + \mathcal{O}(n) = \frac{{2\varphi }}{3}n^{3/2}  + \mathcal{O}(n).
$$

Comment: Your $B_n$ is a really good approximation. (+1)

Comment: Better is: $$\sum _{k=1}^n \left\lfloor \phi  \sqrt{k}\right\rfloor \approx -\frac{n}{2}+\phi  H_n^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$.Mathematica code: `-(n/2) + GoldenRatio* HarmonicNumber[n, -(1/2)]`

Comment: It’s fail https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5Bfloor%28-n%2F2%2Bgoldenratio+%28Harmonic%28n%29%29%5E%28-1%2F2%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C50%7D%5D